# Die Faxen dicke haben - woher kommt das?

Tags: phrase

Ich frage mich gerade woher der Ausdruck "Jetzt hab' ich die Faxen dicke!" kommt.

Hat "Faxen" was mit den störenden Geräuschen (Piepen) eines Faxgerätes zu tun? Und "Dicke" mit der Breite der Zorntoleranzgrenze?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### [Die Faxen dicke haben](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/die_Faxen_dicke_haben)

> *salopp, umgangssprachlich:* genug haben, seine Geduld verloren haben, nichts mehr tolerieren.

Hier sind zwei umgangssprachliche Begriffe in einer Wendung vereint:

#### [Faxe](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Faxe&view=1):

*2. nur im Plural:* dummer, alberner Spaß, Unsinn *umgangssprachlich
ostmitteldeutsch, berlinisch, salopp*

> **Etymologie**: f. *alberner Spaß, Narrheit*. Das seit dem 18. Jh. in der Umgangssprache meist im Plur. übliche Faxen wird auf ein in Mundarten geläufiges Verb **fickfacken** *hin- und herlaufen* zurückgeführt, wobei ein Substantiv **Fickesfackes** als Übergang gedient haben mag (s. **ficken**). Als anderer möglicher Anknüpfungspunkt bietet sich das ausgestorbene Verb frühnhd. **fatzen** *spotten, zum Narren halten* an (s. **Fatzke**). <sup>DWDS</sup>

#### [dicke:](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dicke)

*Adverb: reichlich, vollauf [genug]*

> **Etymologie:** mittelhochdeutsch *dicke*, althochdeutsch *dicco* (Adverb von dick) = oft, häufig <sup>Duden</sup>

Comment: hm what does *ficken* have to do with this?

Comment: [*"alte Bedeutung: unruhig hin und her fahren"*](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=ficken&view=1) :D

Comment: Ob "fickfacken" auch für "Fix und Fax" ( http://www.ddr-comics.de/fix.htm ) Pate gestanden hat?

Comment: Eher [Fix und Foxi](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fix_und_Foxi) ;)

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt das Wort Fax/Faxe/Faxen auch bei Studentenverbindungen, siehe [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fax_%28Studentenverbindung%29). Es handelt sich dabei im Prinzip um Diener im Sinne von "Butler", die früher auf den Häusern von Studentenverbindungen gearbeitet haben. Dabei muss es ein sehr undankbarer Job gewesen sein, da die Faxen oft schikaniert und schlecht behandelt wurden. Wenn Faxe von "Hin- und herlaufen" kommt, macht es Sinn, Bedienstete, die ständig am Herumrennen sind, so zu nennen.

Da viele Sprichwörter und Redewendungen aus dem Bereich der Studentenverbindungen entspringen (z. B. pauken, "xxx aller Couleur"), wäre das eine mögliche Herkunft für die Redewendung. Angenommen, die Diener benehmen sich nicht oder machen Fehler, so könnte man gesagt haben "ich habe die Faxen dicke" = "ich habe genug von den Dienern". Habe natürlich keinen Beweis oder eine Quelle … ist nur eine Möglichkeit :)

Answer (score -3):

Nur eine Vermutung, aber könnten die

> Faxen

nicht vom lateinischen

> facere

(machen, tun; *facit* = er macht) kommen, also etwas wie ***Getue*** heißen?

Ich hoffte, über das englische

> fake

weiteren Aufschluss zu bekommen. Das recht zuverlässige etymonline.com sagt zu *fake*:

> Of unknown origin; attested in London criminal slang as adjective (1775, "counterfeit"), verb (1812, "to rob"), and noun (1851, "a swindle;" of persons 1888, "a swindler"), but probably older. [...] Or it may be from Latin facere "to do".

und kommt also ebenfalls über die bloße Vermutung nicht hinaus.